# asp.net MVC 4 Telerik Grid Ajax issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

i am facing an issue with mvc telerik grid 
there is my view :

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.EmployeeList)
.Name("EmployeeGrid")
.Columns(colums =>
    {
        colums.Bound(e => e.First_Name);
        colums.Bound(e => e.Last_Name);
        colums.Bound(e => e.Hire_Date);
        colums.Bound(e => e.Home_Phone);
    })
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_AjaxBinding", "Home"))
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(paging=>paging.PageSize(10))
    .Filterable()
    )
```

and there is my controller code

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _AjaxBinding(GridCommand command)
    {
        using (var contax=new NorthwindEntities()){
            int pagesize=command.PageSize;
            int page=command.Page;

            var EmployeeList = (from items in contax.Employees
                                select new
                                {
                                    items.First_Name,
                                    items.Last_Name,
                                    items.Hire_Date,
                                    items.Home_Phone
                                });
            return View(new GridModel
            {
                Data = EmployeeList
            });
        }
    }
```

on load the data is loaded correctly from database but internal server error 500 occur when i click on paging  or sort data.

thanks in advance.

Comment: you can see error detail in browser console.or post the error message here so that we can help you out.

Comment: Error! the requested URL returned 500 - Internal Server Error

Comment: have you checked developer tool in response tab?there would be incoming response including detailed server error (asp.net server error) not the browser one.

Comment: on console there is only one error "the requested URL returned 500 - Internal Server Error"

Comment: what browser you are using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21434/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-wasif)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using a Linq query inside a disposable scope.but the query execution is deferred until using it (when you have left `using {}` scope).
and you'r context is disposed!
solution :

add `.ToList` at the end of query :

```
var EmployeeList = (from items in contax.Employees
                                select new
                                {
                                    items.First_Name,
                                    items.Last_Name,
                                    items.Hire_Date,
                                    items.Home_Phone
                                }).ToList();
```